# Why "render" doesn't rerender UI with updated state?

Tags: javascript

I'm playing around with modules and classes and I have created Component class and **App** class that inherits **Component** class. My render method is in Component class. When I "removeItem" I can log and see that my "this.state" is changed but afterward, I call "this.render()", it gets called but it doesn't rerender with my new "this.state" with only one item. Why is that? How can I make it work?

```
document.componentRegistry = {}

class Component {
  constructor(wrapper, props) {
    this._id = Math.random()
    document.componentRegistry[this._id] = this
    this.wrapper = wrapper
    if (props) {
      this.props = props
    }
  }

  render() {}
  onMount() {}

  init() {
    this.wrapper.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', this.render())
    this.onMount()
  }

  update() {
    this.wrapper.textContent = ''
    this.wrapper.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', this.render())
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args)
    this.state = {
      items: [{ name: 'name-1', id: 1 }, { name: 'name-2', id: 2 }]
    }
    this.init()
  }
  render() {
    return `<div class="some-class" id="someId" >
                <ul>${this.state.items
                  .map(({ name, id }) => {
                    return `<li id=${id} class='list-item' onclick="document.componentRegistry[${
                      this._id
                    }].removeItem(this)">${name}</li>`
                  })
                  .join('')}
                </ul>
             </div>`
  }

  removeItem(element) {
    const elId = parseInt(element.id)
    this.state = { items: this.state.items.filter(item => item.id !== elId) }
    this.update()
  }

  onMount() {
    alert('App is successfully mounted!')
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I add update method on the parent class. Does this seem to be a good approach?

Answer (score 0):

found the bug:

Changed init:

```
  init() {
    this.wrapper.textContent = ''
    this.wrapper.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', this.render())
    this.onMount()
  }
```

and calling it instead of render after update

Comment: I think the bug came about because you have the wrong naming scheme. `init` suggests that you want something to be initialized - but you're tasking the init method with stuff that takes care of rendering. If you'd have something that always flushes your rendering output to the DOM I think this would've been easier to reason about.

Comment: how would I change it for the better then?